# Spring Integration outbound FTP append to existing file

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I want to use the outbound FTP channel adapter to APPEND to an existing remote file. However, it looks like the adapter only support the PUT command?

Does anyone know if this is possible with Spring Integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending to remote files is not currently available out of the box, but it would be a good addition, please open a [JIRA New Feature Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

However, all is not lost, you can use a `<service-activator/>` to invoke a bean that creates an `FTPClient` object, using its `appendFile()` method.